# How to make a FOR loop to move files to directory based on file extension

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

Im trying to sort thousands of files and put them in their own folder based on file extension. For example, JPG files to go into a JPG folder.

How can I create a for loop to address this?

What I have attempted to far:

```
# This listed out all the file extensions and the count for each extension:
find . -type f | rev | cut -d. -f1 | rev  | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort | uniq --count | sort -rn
```

```
#This was able to find all jpegs in the media folder
find /media -iname '*.jpg'
```

```
# This worked, however the MV command does not create the folder
find /media -iname '*.jpg' -exec mv '{}' /media/genesis/Passport/consolidated/jpg/ \; #
```

Im guessing that the for loop would be something like but I cant seem to figure it out:

```
for dir in 'find /media -iname "*.jpg"'; do
    mkdir $dir;
    mv $dir/*;
done
```

Comment: How many levels of directory are in `/media`? It's possible using `find`, but if you are finding recursively, and moving to a single directory, you have to decide how to handle duplicate file names. Especially if there's lots of `DSC_0001.JPG`. There's also `exiftool`, which can create file and directory naming schemes from the images' meta data.

Comment: in your loop check *'echo ${dir##\*/}; echo ${dir%/\*}'*

Comment: @dan There is only one level of folders, but there are about 100 folders. Each one has about 500-600 files.  (I had to recover a media hard drive that has a partition erased, and the file structure was not maintained)

Comment: If you use `rename`, also known as `Perl rename` or `prename`, you will have several benefits 1) you don't need a loop, 2) you don't need to create output directories, as it makes them for you, 3) you can do a *"dry run"*, 4) you can use the power of Perl regexes to extract, lower-case and fiddle with filenames and 5) it won't clobber files if you move `1.jpg` from two different directories into a common destination.

Answer (score 0):

To find all the files of a particular extension and move then to a destination we can use `find` command as follows:

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -exec mv {} $destination/ \;
```

This being the critical logic, you can just create a for loop on top of this to iterate through all the known file extensions in your media folder

```
## List all the known extensions in your media folder.
declare -a arr=("jpg" "png" "svg")

## Refer question 1842254 to get all the extentsions in your folder.
## find . -type f | perl -ne 'print $1 if m/\.([^.\/]+)$/' | sort -u


## now loop through the above array
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   echo "$i"
   ## Create a directory based on file extension
   destination="$i"
   mkdir $destination
   find /media -iname "*.$i" -exec mv {} $destination/ \;
done
```

Note that you can change your destination to be whatever you want. I just left it in the same directory.

Here is an executable shell script for your reference: https://onlinegdb.com/NEQSpojhM

Comment: this run entire disk three times. it won't find JPG

Comment: You can use `-iname` flag with `find` command to make it case-insensitive. And as for running the disk three-times, I took the liberty of being non-optimal since this is only going to be a one time job :)

Comment: yes that's how OP did. you should not answer my comments but edit your answer to avoid getting downvoted. consider [optimizing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55973) your non-optimal code ;)